# conversion of date in string variable to date variable

Tags: java, jsp

how to convert date in string variable to date variable..??
Date in database is in yyyy-MM-dd format..
im entering in dd-MM-yyyy format..and trying to convert it in db format so that i can use 'between' query.. code is below

```
        <%String date1=(String)request.getAttribute("from");%>

        <%String date2=(String)request.getAttribute("to");%>
        <%String empcode=(String)request.getAttribute("occ");%>
        <%SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");%>
        <%Date date = new Date(); %>


        <%Date fromdate=formatter.parse(date1);%>
        <%Date todate=formatter.parse(date2);%>
```

Comment: variable fromdate and todate are unable to fetch date..showing null value

Comment: What does the actual string `date1` look like? You've mentioned two different formats in your code. If the `date1` string looks like `2013-12-19`, then that code will work. If it's `19-12-2013` then that code won't work because you've told `SimpleDateFormat` to use `"yyyy-MM-dd"`.

Comment: Are you sure that date1 and date2 are populated correctly?

Comment: date1 is 11-12-2013 ..i want to convert this into yyyy-MM-dd so that i can use it in db query

Answer (score 1):

You're using [`getAttribute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29), but I suspect you wanted [`getParameter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) (if you're trying to get information submitted as part of a `GET` or `POST` request).

Here's what `getAttribute` works with:

> Attributes can be set two ways. The servlet container may set attributes to make available custom information about a request. For example, for requests made using HTTPS, the attribute `javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate` can be used to retrieve information on the certificate of the client. Attributes can also be set programatically using `setAttribute(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)`. This allows information to be embedded into a request before a `RequestDispatcher` call.

Here's what `getParameter` works with:

> Returns the value of a request parameter as a String, or null if the parameter does not exist. Request parameters are extra information sent with the request. For HTTP servlets, parameters are contained in the query string or posted form data.

Looking at the date formatting, you've mentioned two different formats in your question. If the `date1` string looks like `2013-12-19`, then that code will work. If it's `19-12-2013` then that code won't work because you've told `SimpleDateFormat` to use `"yyyy-MM-dd"` but you want `"dd-MM-yyyy"`.

In both cases, the way to debug this is to look at what `date1` and `date2` contain. That would point the way toward how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date fromdate=formatter.parse(date1);
SimpleDateFormat formatter2=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String newDate1 = formatter2.format(fromdate);
```

newDate1 is now in format yyyy-MM-dd.
You can again create the date object with the new string

```
formatter2.parse(newDate1);
```

but not necessary I suppose

Comment: @T J crowder i had used setattribute in the servlet and getting that value in jsp page..